# Swift Accessing Data Structure Inside Cell Setup

Tags: ios, swift

I am appending a Firebase Data snapshot to a NSObject of items being a "customer", "employee", and "business". Set up like this:

```
var customerData = [CustomerData]()
var employeeData = [EmployeeData]()
var businessData = [BusinessData]()

func getCustomerData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("user_profiles").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.customerData.append(CustomerData(snapshot: snapshot))
    })
}

func getEmployeeData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("employees").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.employeeData.append(EmployeeData(snapshot: snapshot))
    })
}

func getBusinessData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.businessData.append(BusinessData(snapshot: snapshot))
    })
}
```

**Data structure is the same for customer, employees, and business as below**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CustomerData: NSObject {

var customerName: String?
var customerPicture: String?
var customerUID: String?

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        customerName = dictionary["name"] as? String
        customerUID = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        customerPicture = dictionary["profPicString"] as? String
    }
}
}
```

I just want to access this snapshot data inside the cell to keep my message details up-to-date, like the profile picture and name. Below is my cell set up:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    cell.chatLogController = self

    let customer = customerData
    let employee = employeeData
    let business = businessData

    let message = messages[indexPath.row]

    cell.message = message
    cell.customer = customer
    cell.employee = employee
    cell.business = business

    setupChatMessageCell(cell,message,customer,employee,business)

    if let text = message.text {
        cell.textView.text = text
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateSizeOfText(text).width + 32
        cell.textView.isHidden = false
    } else if message.imageUrl != nil {
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = 200
        cell.textView.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.playButton.isHidden = message.videoUrl == nil

    return cell
}

    private func setupChatMessageCell(_ cell: ChatMessageCell, _ message: GroupMessage, _ customer: CustomerData, _ employee: EmployeeData, _ business: BusinessData) {


    if message.fromId == customer.customerUID {
        //outgoing messages
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = ChatMessageCell.blueColor
        cell.textView.textColor = .white
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .gray
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLabel.text = message.name?.description
        //cell.nameLabel.text = message.customerName
    } else if message.fromId == employee.employeeUID {
        //incoming messagese
        let customerImage = employee.employeePicture
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(customerImage!)
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.nameLabel.text = message.name?.description
    } else if message.fromId == business.businessUID {
        let customerImage = business.businessPicture
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(customerImage!)
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.nameLabel.text = message.name?.description
    }

    if let imageUrl = message.imageUrl {
        cell.messageImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageUrl)
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = .clear
    } else {
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't think accessing it as a "[index.path]" is the correct way just how I am doing with "messages". How can I access these data structures within the cell setup so I can keep my users information always up-to-date? I am getting errors like "Cannot assign value of type '[CustomerData]' to type 'CustomerData?'" so what is the proper way to access these data structures inside the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't think accessing it as a "[index.path]" is the correct way just how I am doing with "messages".

This is not true. Passing `row` or `item` property of `IndexPath` as index of element in data source array is correct way how to get certain element.

But, you're using `UICollectionView`, so you should use `item` property instead of `row` even if functionality is the same

**UITableView**

```
let item = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
```

**UICollectionView**

```
let item = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item]
```

---

But you should never pass certain cell as parameter for some other method where you're setting it.

Instead in your collection view cell subclass create method for setting cell's views etc.

```
class ChatMessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    var message: Message!
    ...
    func setupCell() {
        ... // here you can work with cell's properites e.g. message, ...
    }
}
```

... and then call it in `cellForItemAt`

Inside this method you should change things connected with content. "Cosmetic" stuff like changing color of views, etc. you can set inside overridden `UICollectionViewCell`'s method `prepareForReuse()`

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    ...
}
```